# In Hadoop Map-Reduce, Is the output of the reducer written one line at a time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I have configured 3 reducers for my AWS EMR Hadoop Map-Reduce streaming job in python.
The data size is 900mb and is read from S3.

Say my reducer function snippet is as follows:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    key, value = line.split('\t')
    print(key)
```

Each reducer writes 300mb of data to S3. So in all 3 files each 300mb were written as there are 3 reducers configured for the job.

Is the 300 mb of each file written one line at a time, or does the reducer queue the data to be written and write it at the end?

Comment: It will depend on the `DataSource` you write to I recon.

Comment: I am writing to AWS S3

Comment: In what format? Although I'm sure there will be some sort of buffering in any case.

Comment: the file is written json format